# MySQL unions and removing semi-similar rows

Tags: mysql, union

I have a union held in a view that's a combination of two tables - a mortality table and a clinical timeline table. The mortality table will contain, at most, one entry per patient (for obvious reasons), and the timeline can contain multiple entries.

The problem I have is that sometimes users record mortality in the mortality table, sometimes in the timeline table, and sometimes in both. I can't use the 'Distinct' keyword, since the rows are slightly different, as they also contain the source table name.

Consequently, I can end up with stuff like this:

```
pat_key, date, event, source
1, 2018-03-01, died, p_mortality
1, 2018-03-01, died, p_events
1, 2018-02-01, admitted, p_events
```

The union is pretty straightforward one - e.g.

```
select pat_key, mmdate as `date`, 'died' as event, 'p_mortality' as source from p_mortality
union distinct
select pat_key, evdate as `date`, evevent as event, 'p_timeline' as source from p_timeline
```

Is there any obvious trick I can use to clobber one of the semi-duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the rows using an aggregation function eg: group_concat

```
  select pat_key, `date`, event, group_concat(source)
  from 
  (
    select pat_key, mmdate as `date`, 'died' as event, 'p_mortality' as source from p_mortality
    union 
    select pat_key, evdate as `date`, evevent as event, 'p_timeline' as source from p_timeline
  ) t 
  group by pat_key, `date`, event
```